# Rails Carrierwave conditional file manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I have a model in rails called document in which user uploads a file.
I am using carrierwave for upload functionality.
What I require is that if the uploaded file is an image then applly some manipulations to it(such as scale to smaller size, remove exif data etc), otherwise save it as is.
How can this be done?
Also if an uploader dosen't have to do any image manipulation, do we need to uncomment

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

in uploader.rb file?

```
# encoding: utf-8

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [500, 500]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: how do i implement conditional file manipulation here?

Comment: can you show your source file please?

Comment: what kind of manipulation you want to do?

Comment: i can manage the manipulation, i only need to know how to check that the file is an image before making changes...